# jQuery - Access form items through function

Tags: jquery

I found on some examples on the web that people were passing the form to a function and then they were only using the id of the item to access it like in :

```
<form id="frm">
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" value="some value" />
</form>

<script>
console.log(getelementval("#frm"));

function getelementval(frm) {
return frm.textbox.val();
}
</script>
```

But FireBug tells me that frm.textbox is undefined... Then I'm searching why it doesn't work on the net but I didn't find anything explaining this option and how to use it.
Any clues?

Comment: Why would you use this ugliness if you have jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to modify the JS slightly to make this work:

```
function getelementval(frm) {
    return $(frm)[0].textbox.value;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gdZEK/2/**

- `$(frm)` returns an element matching the selector.
- `[0]` fetches the actual DOM element.
- `.textbox` works on DOM elements only, not jQuery objects. It matches `[name='textbox']`.
- `.value` needs to be used instead of `.val()`, as `.textbox` isn't a jQuery object.

Honestly, I don't really see how this is better than just using jQuery:

```
$('#frm input[name="textbox"]').val();
```

Comment: @bažmegakapa agreed. +1-able even without :-) see the revisons :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is pure JavaScript and not JQuery

```
function getelementval(frm) {
   var f = document.getElementById(frm);
   return f.textbox.value;
}

console.log(getelementval("frm"));
```

JQuery version

```
function getelementval(frm) {
   var f = $(frm)[0];
   return f.textbox.value;
}

console.log(getelementval("#frm"));
```

Comment: this is not the normal way to do it with jQuery, but the vanillaJS method is good for reference

Comment: the JQuery stuff could get messy - I just wanted to keep it simple and clear